# sed or awk: replace with the count of prior occurrence

Tags: awk, sed

In a text file looks like:

```
label_a 8 label_b 5
label_c 9 label_a 3
label_a 2 label_c 16
label_b 21 label_b 1
...
```

how to replace those numbers with the actual count of prior occurrence of the preceding label, and so the result will look like:

```
label_a 1 label_b 1
label_c 1 label_a 2
label_a 3 label_c 2
label_b 2 label_b 3
...
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with `sed`, but would be trivial with `awk`.

Comment: `sed` doesn't have arithmetic, it doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: Thank you! I though it was a sed function, but an awk solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is better tool for this job:

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) $i = ++freq[$(i-1)]} 1' file
```

```
label_a 1 label_b 1
label_c 1 label_a 2
label_a 3 label_c 2
label_b 2 label_b 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your input, you can do:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<NF;i+=2) printf "%s %s ", $i, ++arr[$i]; print ""}' file
label_a 1 label_b 1 
label_c 1 label_a 2 
label_a 3 label_c 2 
label_b 2 label_b 3
```